# Need Help to Convert Callbacks to Promise

Tags: javascript, promise, callback

I don't know how to convert this Callback into a Promise (result, error). Can you show me how it's made and explain with comments?

```
function calcular() 
{
        let conta = 0;;
        var N1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value);
        var opção = document.getElementById("op").value;
        var N2 =  parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);

        if (opção === "+")
        {
            conta = N1 + N2;

        }
}

function MostrarResultado(conta) 
{

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "O resultado da sua conta é = " + conta;

}

function Executar(callback)
{
    callback(calcular());
}

function xpto()
{
    setTimeout(function() {Executar(MostrarResultado)}, 3000);
}
```

Comment: this is not really a callback pattern and please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: Basically im doing a simple caulculator in JS, using a callback when the calculation is finished. Now i have to do a version with a Promise (result and error)

Comment: function successCallback(result) {
  console.log("It succeeded with " + result);
}

function failureCallback(error) {
  console.log("It failed with " + error);
}

Comment: What are you trying to achieve by using a promise?

Comment: Resolve: Calculates an operation according to the values ​​entered by the user; Reject: Displays an error message indicating that the operator is not defined.
Catch: displays error message when not entered by an operator;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

its not 100% clear on what you want but here is a quick example of what i think your asking for

so to make your function use promises instead of callback you could do something like this

```js
function promiseFunction(){
    return new Promise(resolve =>{
        resolve(result);
    }
}
```

and when you want to get the data that the function returns you could do this

```js
function getInfoFromFunction(){
    promiseFunction(arg).then(result => {
        console.log(result)
    });
}
```

Comment: no problem man :) if this answered your question can you please mark it as answered

Comment: if your question is answered please mark it so if not let me know and I can iterate on my answer to help you